# "Didn’t you think she should have had a doctor" — why "should have"?

Tags: modal-verbs

From *To Kill a Mockingbird*. Atticus is defending a man who allegedly raped and beat up a girl (named Mayella Ewell) in her house. Her father states that he was returning home when he heard his daughter screaming. He ran up to a window and saw that man raping her. Realizing that they weren't alone, the man ran out of the house. Atticus is questioning Mayella's father.

> “Let’s see, you say you ran to the house, you ran to the window, you ran inside, you ran to Mayella, you ran for Mr. Tate. Did you, during all this running, run for a doctor?”
>
> “Wadn’t no need to. I seen what happened.”
>
> “But there’s one thing I don’t understand,” said Atticus. “Weren’t you concerned with Mayella’s condition?”
>
> “I most positively was,” said Mr. Ewell. “I seen who done it.”
>
> “No, I mean her physical condition. Did you not think the nature of her injuries warranted immediate medical attention?”
>
> “What?”
>
> “Didn’t you think she **should have had** a doctor, immediately?”

Why does Atticus say "should have had" instead of "should have"? As far as I know, the modal "should" isn't usually backshifted in past contexts. For example:

> "You **should** tell him what you know."
>   => She said I **should** tell him what I knew.

This can be said at any time, as far as I know. [This post on WR](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/reported-speech-would-should-could.3597378/post-18311150) also supports this idea.

---

My guess is that the "should have" in the above excerpt refers to the moment Mr. Ewell ran up to his daughter after he saw her being raped. While (or after) running for Mr. Tate, Mr. Ewell should have thought, "She should have had a doctor (back then when I was in the house)."

In other words, I think the "should have" here is comparable to the past perfect tense (*had + VERBed*).

Comment: Yes, you are right. If Mayella had really just been raped that day, she _ought to have had [attention from] a doctor_. Mr Ewell should have said to himself "She should have a doctor".

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks. Just to make sure, Atticus is asking if Mr. Ewell thought of getting a doctor for Mayella *after* his opportunity to do so was *gone*. Right?

Comment: No, he is asking why Mr E didn't think of calling a doctor straight away.

Comment: @KateBunting Let's assume Mr. Ewell did think of calling a doctor. What would he have said to Atticus then, *I thought she should have a doctor immediately* or *...should have had...*?

Comment: Also, when do you assume he thought of that, at the time he was standing near Mayella or some other time?

Comment: I don't assume, because we know he didn't. But a woman who had been raped _should have had_ medical attention immediately. In changing what he said to simpler language, Atticus keeps to the same tense. I agree that he could logically have said "Didn't you think she should have a doctor immediately?"

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you! By "assume" I meant assume in my hypothetical scenario two comments above (I wrote two comments one after another because I couldn't edit the first one).