# Should have + past participle vs. Should have had + past participle

Tags: difference

1. You **should have cleaned** the room, before your visitors arrived.
2. [You **should have had  cleaned** the room, before your visitors arrived.](https://old.reddit.com/r/EnglishLearning/comments/cazyt1/does_this_sentence_make_sense_to_you_you_should/etc3oci/)

I know that 1 is correct, but what about 2? How does 1 differ from 2?

##### Three example sentences from Google Books

3. *Recollections of a Marine Attack Pilot* (2012) by Larry R. Gibson, [page 193](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Recollections_of_a_Marine_Attack_Pilot/7XbwuLBboZcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22should%20have%20had%20gotten%22&pg=PA193&printsec=frontcover).

> After that, I would think of her occasionally, remembering what a
> deserving young woman she had been, and that she **should have had   gotten** a better break in life. And several years later, after thinking of her again, it finally dawned on me what a great opportunity I had had on that
> September night in 1962.

4. [Reports from Committees of the House of Commons, Volume 7, (1806)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Reports_from_Committees_of_the_House_of/BjJDAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22should%20have%20had%20received%22&pg=PA217&printsec=frontcover)

> To Colonel John Braithwaite, commanding the Troops marching to Anjengo.
>
> Sir,
> I am directed by the Honourable the President and Select Committee, to desire you will not embark the  detachment at *Anjengo* till you receive their further orders, unless you **should have had received** such advices from *Tellicberry* as may remove every idea of *Hyder Ally*’s design of supporting the French at *Mabé*, and that you have the greatest probability of making an early and speedy conquest of that place.

5. Innovative Data Communication Technologies and Application, Proceedings of ICIDCA 2021, [page 505](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Innovative_Data_Communication_Technologi/Dk1hEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22should%20have%20had%20investigated%22&pg=PA505&printsec=frontcover).

> [Selemawit [6] selected only two healthcare centers: Black Lion and Korean Hospitals to investigate the security and privacy situation. However, the
> researcher identified that the implementation of HIS in healthcare centers is different. In this case, the researcher **should have had investigated** more than two centers.

[ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/491866) closed a similar question. Nobody answered [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/232307).

Comment: 1 is correct English; 2, 3, 4, and 5 are errors.

Comment: In the links you provide, **had** is the main verb, so **should have had** is correct.  In your example, **cleaned** is the main verb, and **had** is redundant. As Michael says, all the passages you quote must be errors.

Comment: Also, there should be no comma in 1